# ExecuteUpdateAsync in EF Core 7.0: set property based on Logic throws InvalidOperation Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am working on data intensive table that contains more than 100.000 records. I need to retrieve a column and update it via logic implemented in an extension method.

For example:

```
var updateResult = await _context.WebidPersons.ExecuteUpdateAsync(x => x.SetProperty(a => a.EmployeeInfo, x => x.EmployeeInfo.ReturnAsEncrypted());
```

The extension method is simply like that

```
public static string ReturnAsEncrypted(this string value)
{
  // logic that encrypt the EmployeeInfo
}
```

The output is an exception

> System.InvalidOperationException the expression could not be translated. Additional information: The following lambda argument to 'SetProperty' does not represent a valid property to be set: 'x => x.EmployeeInfo.ReturnAsEncrypted'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
> Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational

Comment: Encrypting directly directly on the DB might be another option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 2):

[`ExecuteUpdateAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#basic-executeupdate-examples) performs all work server-side (i.e. it is translated into something like `UPDATE [t] SET [t].[EmployeeInfo] = ... FROM [Table] AS [t]`), so EF Core needs to translate `x.EmployeeInfo.ReturnAsEncrypted()` into valid SQL. `ReturnAsEncrypted` seems to be some custom function which is not translated by default. One way is to look into [mapping a method to a SQL function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping) if it is possible to translate `ReturnAsEncrypted` into SQL. Otherwise you will need to fetch data and updated in on the client side using standard EF Core approach.